# Discriminant validity between traits that co-vary?

Tags: correlation, validation, psychometrics, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm hoping to do a validation study on a measure of anxiety (called the AISCs) in a stroke population, using convergent and divergent validity.

A test demonstrates convergent validity if it correlates highly with another measure of the same theoretical construct (one that has already been validated), while divergent validity is demonstrated if there is poor correlation with a measure of a theoretically separate construct (a high correlation with a distinct construct may suggest your measure is not accurate/specific to the construct you wish to measure).

Together, they indicate that the test measures the construct you want it to measure (in my case anxiety) and **ONLY** this construct (as opposed to similar but theoretically distinct constructs, such as depression). To clarify, you want a high Pearson's r correlation between your test and the convergent measure, but a low correlation with the divergent measure.

I am in the process of planning the design. The patients will be administered 3 measures: The AISCs, and two previously validated measures, the HADS-anxiety and HADS-depression. The HADS-anxiety is the convergent measure and the HADS-depression is the divergent.

The problem is, in stroke patients, anxiety and depression strongly co-occur, which may mean my divergent Pearson r values would be high due to the co-morbidity of the two psychological constructs, rather than because of poor divergent validity (i.e. because the AISCs measures depression when it should not). Ideally, you would want the two constructs to be completely independent and have no association (although this rarely occurs for similar constructs in real life)

In crude terms, if the co-occurrence of depression and anxiety in the population is r=0.7, and my divergent validity was ~0.7, you could argue that the test demonstrates good divergent validity, despite a high r value between the AISCs and the divergent measure. However, this is just a case of 'eyeballing', and isn't statistically robust.

In terms of a solution, if I were to correlate the divergent and convergent measures (HADS-anxiety with HADS-depression), I'd have an estimate of the co-occurrence of the two disorders in the sample / population.

My questions are:

1. Is there a statistical test that can control for this co-occurrence when conducting my divergent validity correlation (between the AISCs and the HADS-depression)?
2. Is it logically sound to use a fisher's r-z transformation to compare the effect sizes of the HADS-anxiety / HADS-depression correlation with the AISCs / HADS-depression correlation?

Comment: Something interesting to add is that the cut-offs for desirable convergent/divergent correlations are subjective. I generally go for the ratio of explained variance to unique. If my R^2 is above 0.5, at least 50% of the variance is shared, and tests that measure the same thing should have more variance in common than unique. The problem, however, is that for divergent measures, the proportion of shared variance depends on natural co-occurrence .

Comment: I am voting to leave this closed. Thanks for more background on the science. What's not clear is a) whether you've collected data or are contextalizing published findings b) what conclusions you want to make c) what "convergent/divergent validity/r" is (NB: r is *de facto* the Pearson Correlation to general statisticians).

Comment: @AdamO, I suspect this is clear enough, but we can wait to see if the OP can address your requests for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my post. I have made further edits to try to clarify the outstanding issues outlined by @AdamO.